# Error in Powershell Task with setting $var 'The term 'keyVaultName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

Error message:

> `[error]The term 'keyVaultName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Developing azure devops YAML pipeline.
My inline script in my powershell task

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<REDACTED>'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      Install-Module -Name "AzureAD"
      $keyVaultAdGroup = 'rkimkeyvault'
      $keyVaultName = 'rkaksKeyVault'
```

As you can see I clearly have `$` in front of `keyVaultName` to make this a variable. Not sure why it is trying to see it as a cmdlet.

Comment: Does this is your completed task configuration? I tried the same scripts on my Azure PS task and local powershell command line. All of them are work very fine(No such error displayed). Could you update with more message? Better is the Debug log. I assume there should some configuration make it affected.

Comment: I figured there is something beyond those lines of code that is the problem. So with a divide and conquer approach, I found my problem was this the ( ) around roleNameGUID
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=roleNameGuid]$(roleNameGuid)"
I took those brackets away and it is fine.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you solve it. You can accept your answer shared below:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured there is something beyond those lines of code that is the problem. So with a divide and conquer approach, I found my problem was this the ( ) around roleNameGUID
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=roleNameGuid]$(roleNameGuid)"
I took those brackets away and it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to install, ensure that the AzureRM.KeyVault module is installed and loaded:

```
Install-Module AzureRM.KeyVault
Import-Module AzureRM.KeyVault
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but the issue is not around modules. Remember the PowerShell variable is not recognized as a variable but as a cmdlet or something else.